# Pop up in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup

I have Submit_tag in ruby :

```
<div id="submit-button">
              <%= submit_tag "► #{t('save')}"  %>
          </div>
```

I want create pop up where save button was clicked.
How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your applications.js

if your using jquery write this

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
  alert("was click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way by adding `:confirm`

```
<div id="submit-button">
              <%= submit_tag "► #{t('save')}" , :confirm =>"are you sure?" %>
          </div>
```